# How to convert PixelList to mask?

Tags: matlab, computer-vision

I'm having a `PixelList` containing all set pixels of a binary mask. This looks the following: `PixelList: {[1447x2 int32]}`.

How can I efficiently convert this `PixelList` do a binary mask with dimension `dim`?

The trivial way would be:

```
mask = zeros(dim);
for i=1:length(pixellist)
    mask(pixellist(i,2), pixellist(i,1)) = 1;
end
```

But this is very slow. How to do that efficiently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`sub2ind`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) to get a the linear indexes of the non-zero locations and set them in one shot:

```
pixellist = PixelList{1}; % get the 1447x2 int32 array
mask = false(dim); % e.g. dim = [256 256]
mask(sub2ind(size(mask),pixellist(:,2), pixellist(:,1))) = true;
```

Or use `accumarray` for a more elegant solution:

```
mask = accumarray(fliplr(pixellist),true,dim,@any,false)
```

This could be reduced to just `accumarray(fliplr(pixellist),true,dim)` if there are no repeated elements, and the above syntax is more explicit about the output dimensions.

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility (which is more elegant, in my opinion) is to use sparse matrices:

```
mask = full(sparse(pixellist(:, 2), pixellist(:, 1), true, dim(1), dim(2));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are acquiring this data out of `regionprops`, then try using `'PixelIdxList'` instead of `PixelList`.  That way you would get back the linear indices directly.

```
mask = zeros(dim);
pixlist = PixelIdxList{1};
mask(pixlist) = 1;
```